# Is it possible to determine which PHP file generated some output

Tags: php

Occasionally I have problems whereby a PHP file, somewhere on a large system is producing spurious output in certain situations.

This may be because someone has accidentally typed a space or other character before the `<?php` opening tag, or left an unwanted debugging `echo` in place or included some whitespace after the final closing `?>` tag.

Is there any way to generate a log which shows all the PHP files that generated some output, alongside the output they generated?

If not, is there any other way that can be suggested for tracking down the problem I have described?

Edit: To clarify - the system I'm running is Moodle (not directly relevant, but as it was asked ...) and, on this occasion, the output was during the DB upgrade (but I've had similar problems with random characters being output at other times). There are a very large number of different PHP scripts being loaded into memory to generate the page, so manually spotting the one generating the unwanted output wasn't a very enticing prospect ...

Comment: headers_sent($file, $line) can tell you at least where the first output was generated, see http://docs.php.net/headers_sent

Comment: i guess u'd need access to the web server. Which is possible if its you own personal server.

Comment: on a related note, avoid the `?>` altogether if you can - it's optional and generally a pain when in a purely PHP file.

Comment: You can check network tab of the console log of your browser.

Comment: @user3280126 Not that kind of logging...

Comment: @Daniel Can't we see get, post response of the scripts or html responses in that tab, for example in Chrome?

Comment: @user3280126 Yes, you can. But it does only show you the URI. All PHP scripts to which the request was delegated cannot be shown on the client side.

Comment: The browser will only show the file name which was requested through the browser.

Comment: What framework are you using? and when does it show a spurious output?

Comment: @VolkerK - good suggestion about headers_sent I'll give that a try

Comment: @haxblot - definitely agree about leaving out the closing PHP tags - the question is related to trying to sort out the mess when someone hasn't done that!

Comment: @Tabby I'm working with Moodle (but that wasn't directly relevant to the question, so I left it out). The extra characters appeared during DB upgrade and must have come from one of the many 3rd-party plugins I'd been updating for a client (in a local copy of the code), but there are hundreds of possible files that could have done the output, so I was hoping for a way to narrow things down a little.

Comment: @user3280126 just to clarify - I was looking for a list of all the individual PHP script files that contributed to the output during a single HTTP request (i.e. all those that were included or required from the first script), rather than just the name of the starting PHP file called by the browser (which I already have)

Comment: As a starting point, finish your top-level script with a call to [`get_included_files`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php).  Eg, in `index.php` add to the bottom `file_put_contents('/tmp/mylog', implode("\n", get_included_files()));` -- that will show you at least the files you need to scan for output.  Lots of leg work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your "only" concern is the text outside of php tags [token_get_all()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php) might help you. Everything(?) outside php tags is reported as T_INLINE_HTML (312), so it's easy to filter.
E.g.

```
<?php
for($t=0;$t<10; $t++) { ?>

<?php
}
?>

<?php
$at = token_get_all( file_get_contents(__FILE__) );
foreach($at as $t) {
    if ( is_array($t) && T_INLINE_HTML===$t[0]) {
        echo 'inline html @ line ', $t[2], "\r\n";
    }
}
```

prints (some blank lines and)

```
inline html @ line 3
inline html @ line 7
```

combine that with something like [get_included_files()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php) or [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) and you have a little makeshift tool for the task.

Comment: That looks like a good solution - I'll give it a try and see if it works.

Comment: I wrapped this in a recursive call to scandir (filtered by .php extension), added a check for the length of $t[1] being < 20 and a check for the presence of the letter 's' within it (as that was the visible output in this case). After that, a quick check through the results managed to locate the problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways of doing it but its a time consuming job unless you have written the code . Make sure you turn on error reporting this may also help.

1) Install 
Apachetop

This tool scans your webserver log files showing you which files are being called, it also has a few other interesting features

2)Use `lsof`

```
watch -n1 "lsof | grep '\.php'"
```

The above line of code will only list .php files which have been opened. If the file opens and closes fast it may not be able to list it

3)Use xdebug and xdebug profiler.

While your running the code; simultaneously check xdebug profiler and keep refreshing it.  One of the feature the profiler has is that it draws a visual map of the files being called. You will have to then manually check those files for syntax errors or bad/wrong logic. If you know or if you have made the system it will be a bit ease for you to do it.

I hope this helps

Comment: Error reporting is on and it's a dev server running on my current computer. I've got xdebug installed and xhprof as well (Moodle, the framework I'm using, has built-in support for profiling with xhprof). The problem is that at the point where this code is running there are several hundred PHP files (at least) being loaded, so I was hoping to narrow things down to the ones that actually generated some form of output.